# How to enable "double tap to wake up" in any android device?

Tags: bootloader, kernel

I've heard about the feature "double tap to wake up". How to enable this option on my device
My device details:
Gionee P3 Lollipop Cyanogenmod 12.1
Kernel Version 3.4.67

Answer (score 1):

It can be enabled only if your ROM/ kernel support that feature. To check if it is enabled download [3C Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.at.free) from Play Store , go to *System Manager → Miscellaneous*  and you will have an option that shows up to enable double tap feature, IF it is supported. Figure shows it is not supported on my device

I am not aware if CM supports enabling this feature using the inbuilt settings

[image]